# Depedency errors ubuntu 16.04 when installing any package

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies, apache2, apt-get

Hello I am trying to install apache2 on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine. When I exectute the install command `sudo apt-get install apache2` I get the following error

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-auth-mysql : Depends: apache2.2-common (>= 2.2.3-3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

After that I tried `apt-get -f install` which gave me this error :

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
     /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-fKYr6k/0-apache2.2-bin_2.2.22-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
     /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-fKYr6k/1-apache2.2-common_2.2.22-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I feel like I am stuck in a loop :) Anyone some advice?

Many thanks !!

Comment: Rerun the second command with `sudo`.

Comment: where did `libapache2-mod-auth-mysql` came from? Are you using a ppa or something? AFAIK there is no such package in ubuntu 16.04. See this also https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2015/05/msg00694.html